# WKHTMLTOPDF does not have option to change default unit option?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the wkhtmltopdf for the html to pdf conversion.

But I found that the width and lenght defined using the pixel does not work.

I have set the page size to Letter Landscape means 769 x 612 pixel

But when i go with pdf does not cover the full page space.

Here in some forum I got that wkhtmltopdf has "mm" as default unit.

Also I have tried to search for the default dpi keep by the wkhtmltopdf, but do not get any reference.

When I use this commend to generate pdf..It does not work...No content in PDF

```
$output = exec('./wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64 --disable-smart-shrinking --dpi 72 -L 0mm -T 0mm -s Letter -O Landscape '.$url.' ./getpdf.pdf 2>&1');
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I am also strugling with same question...

Comment: I have tried it now. Totally wrong answer. This does not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by default we can not change unit.

But wkhtmltopdf has capability to add the ratio to manage the size.

Like if your html is for the 72 dpi and you need it in 300dpi then you can do it.

--dpi :: use this for the dpi setting
--zoom :: to check in which zoom your html fit to pdf